# How do I access mat menu trigger from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the following html:

```
<button mat-icon-button #notificationMenuBtn [matMenuTriggerFor]="notificationsMenu">
</button>
<mat-menu #notificationsMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
</mat-menu>
```

How to I access thematMenuTriggerFor on the notificaitonMenuBtn from typescript? I tried using a View Child (shown below) but I can't seem to bind it to the trigger, only to the button.

```
@ViewChild('notificationMenuBtn') notificationMenuBtn : MatMenuTrigger;
this.notificationMenuBtn.openMenu();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to use MatMenuTrigger instead of the element id.

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) notificationMenuBtn: MatMenuTrigger;
```

Comment: This way you will not be able to access a specific menu

Answer (score 21):

If you really need to use an id (When you have several MatMenuTrigger)

```
@ViewChild('notificationMenuBtn', {read: MatMenuTrigger}) protected notificationMenuBtn : MatMenuTrigger;
```