# MatMenuTrigger open programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've seen similar answers but get errors when trying to implement @ViewChild

See issue [53792202](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792202/open-angular-material-menu-programmatically-using-viewchild-on-matmenutrigger)

I have a component which has a search bar and a list of names. The search bar will filter the names in the list appropriately, but I want to have the list display ONLY after there is data in the search bar.

component.html

```
<input class="col-6 form-control searchbar" id="SearchBar" placeholder="Search by name" value="" autofocus [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (input)="searchTerm ? addQueryParams({search: searchTerm}) : addQueryParams({search: null})">


 <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor] = "peoplemenu">People</button>
    <mat-menu #peoplemenu = "matMenu" layout="row" >
       <button mat-menu-item  *ngFor="let person of people | search: searchTerm as result; let i = index" [value]="person.name" class="usernames" (click)="setPersonValue(person.name)">{{person.name}}</button>
    </mat-menu>
```

component.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module'; 
constructor(
    public materials: MaterialModule, 
    ) { }
```

materials.ts

```
peoplemenu: MatMenu;
```

If I add to materials.ts the following line

```
@ViewChild('peoplemenu') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

I get the error: Expected 2 arguments but got one.

I can avoid this error by altering the line to this

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, this.peoplemenu) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

but get the error: cannot read property of 'peoplemenu' of undefined.

Am I suppose to be initializing the menu somehow? Form controls and form groups need to be initialize via

```
constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {  this.addCheckbox();  }

addCheckbox() {
      this.checkboxForm = this.fb.group({
        'EmployeeName':true,
      });
    }
```

but I can find no reference for how to do with the the menu.

If I do NOT include the @ViewChild - the initial button does open the menu

IF I include

```
[matMenuTriggerFor] = "peoplemenu"
```

in the input searchbar the moment I type in the searchbar it brings up the menu, but then the filter no longer works as the focus is in the menu.

The goal is to have a search bar that will trigger the menu, but also filter the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the ref for MatMenuTrigger as follows,

```
@ViewChild('peoplemenu', { static: true }) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

Then you can access the trigger in AfterViewInit life cycle for setting up the state for first time